# I want to add my custome links in header? I tried but it did not work. .Here is my default .xml file code.Someone Please help me

Tags: magento2

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <!--Add Logo-->
            <referenceBlock name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">100</argument> 
                    <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.jpg</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

       <referenceBlock name="header.panel">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="top.links" after="authorization-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Checkout</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">checkout</argument>

                </arguments>
            </block>

             <!--  you can easly Remove  links with following code -->
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />   
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />   
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         
            <referenceBlock name ="footer" remove="true" />                

</referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple and easy way is create custom small custom module and create header Link.

**Step 1:** Add `default.xml` file

Find the path `app/code/module_vendor/module_name/view/frontend/layout`, then add `default.xml` file by:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="header.links">
         <block class="module_vendor\module_name\Block\Link" name="add-new-header-link">
             <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Link</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">new-link</argument>
     </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**Step 2:** Add `Link.php` file

Continue with the path `app/code/module_vendor/module_name/Block` and you will add the link.php file:

```
<?php

namespace module_vendor\module_name\Block;

class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
protected function _toHtml()
    {
     if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
     return parent::_toHtml();
     }
     return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

And Your above code remove and write this code **UPDATE**:-

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Checkout</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Checkout</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Step 3:** Run Some commands like :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Thank you .What's the location of link .php

Comment: Ohh,sorry `module_vendor\module_name\Block\Link.php`

Comment: i have updated the my answer...

Comment: okay i will try this

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Hey can i use widgets approch to create header links with static blocks?

Comment: yes, but not a dynamically

Comment: Hello @tamanna Please check my update code ...

Comment: I am still not able to create custom links.

Comment: Please share your file path

Comment: app/code/Vendor/customemodule/view/fronten/layout/default.xml and my link.php file path is app/code/Vendor/customemodule/Block/link.php

Comment: In my answer add UPDATE answer check and update answer put this file `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and after remove the var/view_process and clear cache

Comment: Thank you now i am able to add new links.

Comment: Welcome @tamanna help this answer so accept answer because this answer useful other community..... Thanks